# NestJs should you test your TypeORM entities?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

should you test your TypeOrm entities if you are trying to perform unit test? if yes, then what's the right approach to do so?

This entity could be an example:

```
@Entity()
export class Dog {

   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id: number;

   @Column()
   name: string;

   @ManyToOne(() => DogFood, dogFood => dogFood.dogFoods, { nullable: true })
   dogFood: DogFood;
}
```

Comment: What about the entity would you be testing?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel The relations, ex: manytoone, onetomany, etc

Comment: But what about it  are you testing?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel my question is if the entity (model) itself is it necessary to be tested (as a class) if you do unit test, im currently using the data mapper approach.

Comment: I get that you're asking if it _should_ be tested. I'm asking back if you _do_ test it, then what is it you're testing?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel since it's not going to test something, i'll exclude for the coverage thing :) thanks for your help.